# How to make boxes align side-by-side instead of on top of each other in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Wondering why the `itemContainer` and `priceContainer` won't show up next to each other?

Do I need to include any kind of file for FlexBox?

I thought it was built into CSS3. Is there a standard add-on to utilize?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#orderContainer {
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#selectionsContainer {
  width: 85%;
}
#catagoryContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(20% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
#menuContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
#itemContainer {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  display: flex;
  order: 1;
}
#priceContainer {
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="orderContainer">
    <div id="itemContainer">
      itemContainer
    </div>
    <div id="priceContainer">
      priceContainer
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="selectionsContainer">
    <section id="catagoryContainer">
      catagoryContainer
    </section>
    <section id="menuContainer">
      menuContainer
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only thing necessary to make two sibling elements show up next to each other is declare `display: flex` on the *parent container*.

You've applied `display: flex` to `.container`. This is not the parent container of `#itemContainer` and `#priceContainer`. You need to apply `display: flex` to `#orderContainer`.

A [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) is limited in scope to a parent / child relationship. Descendants beyond the children will not accept flex properties from an ancestor.

You will always need to apply `display: flex` (or `display: inline-flex`) to parent elements in order for flex properties to work on the children ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276)).

---

Once you've established the flex container, several default settings come into play. Here are two:

- `flex-direction: row` - child elements (flex items) will align horizontally
- `flex-wrap: nowrap` - flex items are forced to stay in a single line

---

Flexbox is a CSS3 technology. You don't need to add any library or other file to make it work. It runs like any other CSS. Just be aware of [browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Comment: Michael, that was everything I needed to know, thank you so much. dip, if ou have any advice I'm all about it. More the marrier! Thank ya'll so much!