# writing CSS for element to wrap

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have tried a hundred different combinations for my menu bar (secondary-menu) to wrap in two rows when viewed in smaller browser screen or device.

The last one I tried was this:

```
@viewport {
width: device-width;

@media only screen and (min-width : 375px) and (max-width : 667px) {
    .secondary-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this code or write another one that automatically shows two rows for the top green menu bar with all buttons on a smaller screen? (The rest of my site is responsive so I don't need to make this work for the whole site, just this element.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi. This is just to point you in the hopefully right direction. Try playing with the fixed position, whitespace nowrap and display. .secondary-menu ul {
    height: 35px;
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 0;
    background-color: #0e6e3e;
    margin: 0 -9999rem;
    padding: .25rem 9999rem;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
} Note that I commented out position fixed and white-space nowrap.

Answer (score -2):

You should first add “height:auto” to your ".secondary-menu ul" class definition.

Then you should add “float:left” to your current stylesheet class, so the class will end up like this:

```
.boldgrid-framework-menu li, .footer-center-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Now when i scale your site, the buttons automatically appear on another row.

Comment: Thank you so much- that fixed the issue.

Comment: If I wanted to have a condition for the tertiary buttons, do you recommend .boldgrid-framework-menu li, .tertiary-menu {
 color: orange;} ?