# Why is an element with width:100% not taking the parent's width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing the issue that I cannot set the same width as its parent inside a flexbox item.

Here is the code and the span with the class `theSpan` doesn't have the same `width` as its parent.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.item1 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.item2 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.item3 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.theSpan {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <span class='theSpan'>abcdefg</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item2'>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item3'>
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: spans are inline elements by default - better use DIVs (= block elements) for elements that you want to define a width or height for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `span` element with class `theSpan` is a child of a flex item (`.item1`).

This flex item is *not* a flex container.

Because [only the children of a flex container participate in flex layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276),
the span (a grandchild) is disqualified. It does not exist in a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers).

The span exists in a standard [*block formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting).

In a BFC, a `span` is, by default, an inline, non-replaced element.

The reason `width: 100%` does not work is provided in the spec:

> [**10.2 Content width: the `width`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-width-property)
>
> This property does not apply to non-replaced inline elements. The
>   content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of the
>   rendered content within them.
>
> [**10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced
>   elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-width)
>
> The `width` property does not apply.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for the explanation and helping me editing the title and content(I am not a native english speaker). I will look more into the CSS foundation.

Answer (score 5):

You should turn the `span` into  `block` via `display`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.item1 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.item2 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.item3 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.theSpan {
  display:block;/* <= display instead or with width will do */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <span class='theSpan'>abcdefg</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item2'>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item3'>
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

make `.item1` a `display:flex` as well then set the `.theSpan` as `flex:1`
and you can set all the items as `flex:0 200px` since you want to have a `flex-basis` of `200px` you don't need to have `flex:1`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 0 200px
}
.item1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.item2 {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.item3 {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.theSpan {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <span class='theSpan'>abcdefg</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item2'>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class='item3'>
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for another approach.

Comment: I just explained  simplified and with an example what @michael_b said with Sources ;)