# padding-top disappears when using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I use `flex` to position my links, the padding doesn't seem to work for `padding-top`.

Here is an example:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <p>title</p>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container a {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #e23311;
}
```

And here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqawkgLk/).

How can I fix this so that the padding applies to the top of the links as well?

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` to your `.container a` rule.

Comment: Sweet that works @LGSon. Want to write it as an answer?

Comment: Perfect, and there is an answer showing it so I closed it as a dupe

Comment: Ah I see. I just didn't understand why this behavior was only occurring when display: flex was applied to the container.

Comment: Me neither actually, so this duplicate might not be 100% correct in this case. I will leave for now, but might alter it later.

Comment: It might be the "margin collapse" issue, here caused by the `margin: 0` on the body, so if you remove that instead it works too.

Comment: I don't think that's all of it. If you don't have `margin: 0` true you get more of the top padding, but still not all of it. I think as you said, you need the `inline-block` to fix the margin collapse on the actual `a` element.

Comment: Didn't check that, good you did. Lets leave it as is until someone complains :)

Comment: Your top padding works fine. It's just hidden because you have `margin: 0` on the `body`. If you provide some space, you'll see the full padding:  https://jsfiddle.net/yqawkgLk/2/

Comment: Because the `a` elements are inline-elements in a block formatting context (they are not part of flex layout), they assume inline-level box characteristics. Namely, they will remain in their line and will not disturb surrounding lines (vertically-speaking).

Comment: Making the anchors inline-block allows them to act more like block-level elements while remaining inline. I posted an answer to a similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39577892/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B thanks for correcting me on that margin thing, I see you are right abt that. And thanks for the explanation... cheers :)