# Element overlapping when absolute positioning applied on a Custom Tag - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I created a custom tag called `<bubble></bubble>` and its styles can be applied using the custom `type` attribute.

*Code:*

```css
bubble[type=normal] {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #5e9bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<bubble type="normal">Hello!</bubble>
```

The problem comes in positioning the element when placed with the `div` tags. First of all, the `width: 50px;` gets ignored unless I use `Position: Absolute;` which has another problem I'll describe below. Second, It partially overlays the text when `<div></div>` tags are used even after applying the margins on Top and Bottom.

*Code with Absolute Positioning:*

```css
bubble[type=absoluteposition] {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #5e9bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<bubble type="absoluteposition">Hello!</bubble>
```

The problem here is `position: absolute;` acts like `float: left;` which I don't want to use even after using margins on top and bottom. This problem also occurs with `div` tags.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qv52aLeu/1/) in JSFiddle.net

If you have a solution **OR** You think there is a problem in my code **OR** You think there is an Alternative way to fix this problem **OR** You need more details on my Question, please Reply.

Comment: Add rule display: inline-block

Comment: Would work with code without Absolute Position but won't work with code with Absolute Positioning.

Comment: In terms of the first problem -- *why `width: 50px` is being ignored* -- that's because *all* elements (including custom elements) have an initial setting of `display: inline` ([**details**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36380684/3597276)). And `width` doesn't apply to `inline` elements ([**details**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39578948/3597276)). Set `bubble` to `display: block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks but `display: inline-block;` won't work with `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to specify , height , width on above when using absolute than you may try wrap bubble tag in another div with relative position like :

```
<div class="some" style="
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
">
<bubble type="absoluteposition">Hello!</bubble>
</div>
```

Cheers !