# Align self doesn't work on an anchor tag when its parent is flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't get the `align-self: center` property to work on an a tag

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.container-link {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="container-link" href="google.com">link</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="container-link" href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Howcome those links aren't aligned in the center now...?

I tried adding flex to the container too but no go

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.container-link {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="container-link" href="google.com">link</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="container-link" href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Why does this not work either?

[align-self: flex-end not working in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527314/align-self-flex-end-not-working-in-flexbox)

> You're applying flex properties to a child of a block element. Such
> properties will be ignored because you're in a block formatting
> context.
>
> Switch from display: block to display: flex to establish a flex
> formatting context.

My parent is flex

[can't get align-self to work in a flexbox container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249564/cant-get-align-self-to-work-in-a-flexbox-container)

Again, same rebuttal, I am flexing and my container is flex?

Why does align self center not work?

Comment: hi, perhaps the parent display should be set?

Comment: add border to the link element to understand

Comment: (1) move the height to the parent + display:flex on parent + align-self on link

Comment: `align-self` is for cross-axis alignment. For example, with a row flexbox, as you're using, it aligns vertically.

Comment: (2) keep the height on link + display:flex on link + align-items on link

Comment: Your issue: you cannot align an element inside a container where the height is defined by that element because there is nothing to align. Align-self apply to the element you want to align so you cannot align what is *inside* the link by using align-self on the link

Comment: I don't have any view as to whether this should be reopened, but it is worth noting that the gold-badge closer is _extremely_ experienced in this technology, and thus the closure is probably correct. If you want to reopen it, a much better justification would be needed.