# Flexbox: centering everything on one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm trying to recreate this layout with flexbox only:

[image]

I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible with minimal markup, however I'm having a hard time vertically centering everything on one line.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#p {
  background: #26272b;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
img {
  width: 1rem;
}
.pp {
  width: 2rem
}
```

```html
<div id="p">

  <div id="pl">
    <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/synchub/imgs/beamed-note.svg" alt="note">
    <h4>A Head Full Of Dreams <span>- Coldplay</span></h4>
  </div>

  <div id="pc">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/synchub/imgs/previous.svg" alt="Click to go back">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="pp" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/synchub/imgs/play.svg" alt="Click to play">
    </a>
    <!-- <a href="#"><img class="pp" src="http://mortenhjort.dk/synchub/imgs/pause.svg" alt="Click to pause"></a> -->
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://mortenhjort.dk/synchub/imgs/next.svg" alt="Click to skip">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="pr"></div>

  <time>00:14 / 00:30</time>

  <div></div>
```

This is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h1k8v16g/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary flex container is working to keep flex items vertically centered.

However, the content of the flex items is still in a *block formatting context*.

Therefore, make the flex items into flex containers with centering:

```
div { display: flex; align-items: center; }
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1k8v16g/2/)

Learn more about the scope of a *flex formatting context* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276

Comment: Great comment! Thanks!