# Unable to achieve automatic equal height with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a three-column layout, but despite using `display: flex` on the container, the children are not automatically getting the same height. I'm not a Flexbox expert, so I'm struggling to identify the issue.

Here is my code:

```css
.events-row {
  display: flex;
}
.events-row .event-card:hover {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img {
  position: relative;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img .series-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont {
  text-align: center;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
      <div class="button-cont">
        <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
      </a>
      <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
      </a>
      <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/gLKeLV.

Comment: They're the same height for me in chrome. That is, if you don't include .button-cont underneath the first column.

Comment: With the exception of the buy tickets bit at the bottom and the hovering, it all looks good to me, can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, without the button, it would be the same height whether I used Flexbox or not because the content would be the same. I'm trying to achieve the same height regardless of the content. So, I'd like to include the button.

Comment: @MarioParra Check out my answer. They are of same height. Put the background to the `.event-card {
  background: #eaeaea;
}`. That fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are of equal heights. When you add a border:

```css
border: 1px solid #ccc;
```

They look the same height. Just that you need to add the background to the parent, which is the `.event-card`.

Alternate solution being adding the background to the `.event-card`:

```css
.events-row .event-card {
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```css
.events-row {
  display: flex;
}
.events-row .event-card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
.events-row .event-card:hover {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img {
  position: relative;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img .series-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont {
  text-align: center;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
      <div class="button-cont">
        <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
      </a>
      <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
      </a>
      <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Use the full screen and check.

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbZLya**

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Give `background-color` to `.event-card`, like:

```
.event-card {
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

Have a look at updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNYEzE) the snippet below (*use full screen*):

```css
.events-row {
  display: flex;
}
.events-row .event-card {
  background: #eaeaea;
}
.events-row .event-card:hover {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img {
  position: relative;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-img .series-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #000;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont {
  text-align: center;
}
.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
      <div class="button-cont">
        <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" /></a>
      <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <div class="event-card-img">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" /></a>
      <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card-info">
      <h1>Event title</h1>
      <h2>Event date</h2>
      <h2>Event venue</h2>
      <p>
        Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
        <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts you need to keep in mind when revising your code:

- The flex equal height column feature applies only to siblings
- The scope of flex layout is limited to the parent-child relationship

You made a top-level container (`.events-row`) a flex container. That means that only the child (`.event-card`) accepts flex properties (and these children are, in fact, equal height siblings).

But you want descendants further down the tree to share equal height. Unless you give their parent container `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`, or maybe use `height: 100%`, they will not have equal height.

Here are more in-depth explanations:

- [Equal Height Columns with Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
- [The scope of a flex formatting context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276)
- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)