# fix elements to the bottom of a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to create part of a page and I have 2 buttons that will open modals in one of the flexbox items. I would like to fix the buttons to the bottom of the item like a footer if possible.

I have created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/harveymj/pen/LLbxbQ) to demo the issue. I have tried several solutions but I can't seem to get the buttons aligned at the bottom. I am relatively new to HTML and CSS so it's very possible that I've missed something trivial.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.one {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 600px;
}

.two {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1.2;
  width: 524px;
  height: 600px;
}

button {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">
    <p> I would like to align the buttons to the bottom of this item </p>
    <button id="Btn1">Open Modal 1</button>
    <button id="Btn2">Open Modal 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p> No buttons for this item </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `.one` `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`, wrap the buttons in an element, and use `justify-content: space-between` on `.one` to push the buttons to the bottom of the column.

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.one{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 450px;
  flex-grow: 1; 
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.two{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px; 
  flex-grow: 1.2;
  width: 524px;
  height: 600px;
}

button {
    background-color: green; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <div class="one">
        <p> I would like to align the buttons to the bottom of this item </p>
        <div class="buttons">
        <button id="Btn1">Open Modal 1</button>
        <button id="Btn2">Open Modal 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <p> No buttons for this item </p>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since flex properties only apply to the children of a flex container, your buttons are not flex items.

The buttons are *descendants* of the flex container (`#container`), but not *children*, so they are beyond the scope of flex layout.

One method to resolve the issue would be to make the parent of the buttons a flex container. Then flex properties can be applied to the buttons.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.one {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;           /* new */
  flex-wrap: wrap;         /* new */
}

p {
  flex: 0 0 100%;          /* new */
}

button {
  margin: auto 10px 0;     /* new */
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.two {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1.2;
  width: 524px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">
    <p> I would like to align the buttons to the bottom of this item </p>
    <button id="Btn1">Open Modal 1</button>
    <button id="Btn2">Open Modal 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p> No buttons for this item </p>
  </div>
```

Learn more about the flex formatting context here:

- [Proper use of flex properties when nesting flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276)

Learn more about flex `auto` margins here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: thank you for the helpful answer and explanation. Quick question, why have you added the `flex` to p in the CSS? What is this doing?

Comment: That makes the `p` element consume the entire width of the row, forcing the buttons to the next line. That's why `flex-wrap` is needed on the container.

Comment: I tried to do it without changing the HTML (often people want no changes to the mark-up). But yes, if you can adjust the mark-up, then [that option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572522/3597276) is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to put your buttons in their own `<div>` like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">
    <p> I would like to align the buttons to the bottom of this item </p>
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button id="Btn1">Open Modal 1</button>
        <button id="Btn2">Open Modal 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="two">
<p> No buttons for this item </p>
</div>
```

and change your css to:

```
#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 450px;
  height: 600px;  
}

.two {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px; 
  flex-grow: 1.2;
  width: 524px;
  height: 600px;
}

 .btn-container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
  }

button {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: I guess someone beat me to the punch!  : )