# Why css wont inherit on their own

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm trying to style a simple website. I'm having trouble with css and particularly with inheritance. My goal is to have side menu and inside it items placed one under another:

```css
#inner-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-menu-navbar {
  display: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left-menu {
  display: inherit;
  background: hotpink;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  background: tomato;
}

.outlet {
  flex: 2;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.footer {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-menu">
    <span class="left-menu-navbar">
        <a routerLink="projects" routerLinkActive="active">Projects</a>
        <a routerLink="upload" routerLinkActive="active">Upload</a>
        <a routerLink="account" routerLinkActive="active">Account</a>
        <a routerLink="create" routerLinkActive="active">Create project</a>
      </span>
    <span>111</span>
    <span>222</span>
    <span>333</span>
  </div>
  <div id="inner-flex-container">
    <span class="header">MENU COMPONENT</span>
    <div class="outlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <span class="footer">vVVVVVVv</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code does the job, but what I'm asking is why I have to explicitly declare in tag `<span class=left-menu-navbar">` css properties as display and explicitly declare direction? I would expect to inherit it from parent (`left-menu`) but that's not happening...

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B This is more about inheritance than Flexbox, so I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why I have to explicitly declare in tag 
>   css properties as display and explicitly declare direction?

The simple answer is:

> Not all CSS properties are inherited, because it doesn’t make sense
>   for some of them to be. For instance, margins are not inherited, since
>   it’s unlikely that a child element should need the same margins as its
>   parent. In most cases common sense will tell you which properties are
>   inherited and which aren’t, but to be really sure you need to look up
>   each property in the [CSS 2.1 specification property summary
>   table](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html).

Src: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade