# Apply display:flex to a form

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to apply display:flex on this form and failing. The structure of the HTML cannot be changed and I can't for the life of me figure out how to go about it.
The only way they all inline (including the button) is to apply flex on both the form **and** .form-fields. But when the form wraps, the button stays in the first row, while the input field for the last name goes into second.

What am I doing wrong? And what can I do with CSS only, without touching the HTML? Thank you!

```css
form, .form-fields {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <div class="form-body">
      <ul class="form-fields">
        <li class="form-field">
          <div class="input-container">
            <span class="name_first">
              <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name *" required="">
            </span>
            <span class="name_last">
              <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name *" required="">
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!--  name and last name -->

        <li class="form-field">
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="email_address" id="email_address" type="email" value="" placeholder="Email *" required="">
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- email adress -->
        <li class="form-field">
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="phone_number" id="phone_number" type="tel" value="" placeholder="Phone *" required="">
          </div>
        </li>
        <!--  phone -->
      </ul>
      <input name="action" type="hidden" value="Request an Info Sheet">
    </div>
    <div class="form-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="form_button">
        <span>Contact Us</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- button -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the elements to never wrap?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B So, if I apply flex to form, its children are .form-body and .form-footer. and those get flex properties, right? I'd need to apply flex to them too, separately? And control how they react to wrapping. Did I get any of that right? Haha

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why did you resort to using flexbox?

Comment: @RMo I'm trying to inline this form and make it so that when it wraps, it wraps as you'd expect it: all input fields first and then button at the end. Sorry if my explanation is a mess. And about flexbox, I'm not sure. I thought that would work best?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Adding `flex-wrap` sends the button to the end of the next row:

```
form, .form-fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox has effect only on direct children. So if you do `display:flex` on a parent, all the direct children will be affected. The nested divs inside the child won't be affected. So `display:flex` on the form will make the `.form-body` and `.form-footer` behave as flex children so these two divs will be in a row.

Applying `display:flex` to `.form-fields` will make all direct children of `.form-fields` i.e lis with the class of `.form-field` into a flex item. So they will align horizontally.

The problem of the wrapping was because the first `.input-container` has two non flex children. So adding flex over there as well will make them stay inline.

So adding this css will horizontally align all items:

```
 form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.form-fields, .input-container{
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want to do. All I did was add: `flex-direction: column;`.

The default value for a flexbox is row. That will make the flex item a row and spread the children out over that row.

Setting value for a flexbox to column, will make the flex item a column and spread the children out over that column.

Hope it helps ;)

```css
form, .form-fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <div class="form-body">
      <ul class="form-fields">
        <li class="form-field">
          <div class="input-container">
            <span class="name_first">
              <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name *" required="">
            </span>
            <span class="name_last">
              <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name *" required="">
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!--  name and last name -->

        <li class="form-field">
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="email_address" id="email_address" type="email" value="" placeholder="Email *" required="">
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- email adress -->
        <li class="form-field">
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="phone_number" id="phone_number" type="tel" value="" placeholder="Phone *" required="">
          </div>
        </li>
        <!--  phone -->
      </ul>
      <input name="action" type="hidden" value="Request an Info Sheet">
    </div>
    <div class="form-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="form_button">
        <span>Contact Us</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- button -->
  </form>
</div>
```