# no whitespace when aligning with flexbox can't align text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm wondering what's causing it not to read any whitespace inbetween the span or p tags as well as why the span doesn't align to the center with everything else?

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

li span {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> <span> Username  </span>
    </a>

    <p> added you as a friend</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `a` is aligned with p AND the span is inside the `a` and flexbox is whitespace-free

Comment: is there a way to make it not whitespace-free?

Comment: control the space using margin

Comment: The `span` is not a flex item. So `align-self: center` is ignored. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;` to create the space.

Or use padding/margin on span.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li span {
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> <span> Username  </span>
    </a>

    <p> added you as a friend</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: don't use `&nbsp;`.. margin is better. this will break text wrapping and the size of the space is not configurable (you'll end up with 2, 3, 4 of these in a row if you use these for spacing regularly)

Comment: oh ok, you mean the nbsp .. Yeah its not a good practice. but i have added 2 answers in it. Plz mention clearly otherwise it will confuse the OP :)