# max-width and flex in IE11 does not work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am having an issue using flex box and max width in IE11.
I did search the web and I saw some solutions but NONE of them worked for me and that is why I posted a new thread.
Here is my code:

```css
.story-img {
  padding: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex:1;
}

.story-img img {
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 story-img">
    <div>
      <img class="img-responsive11" alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/resized.images.stg1.telegraphjournal.com/251861/desktop/comey-mob-analysis-56581436-3f0b-11e8-a7d1-e4efec6389f0.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you see I am using max-width to control the image of a bigger size.
It works in all browsers except IE(I use IE11).
Here is the codepen example of that:
https://codepen.io/hminaee/pen/wXNjBK#code-area

Can you please help me?

Comment: flexbox and max-width have issues in the IE11..one thing you can try is change `max-width` to `width:100%` in `.story-img img`

Comment: Your `img` element has flex properties applied, but it doesn't appear to be a flex item. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276

Comment: You have `flex: 1` applied on `.story-img`. The `flex` property doesn't always work well in IE. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B So does it mean that for IE I need to define it own class of css to use display block instead?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the only thing you're missing is a width limit on the div parent of the image.

Just add this to your code:

```
.story-img > div { width: 100% }
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXOyxm)