# flex-grow not expanding flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First I create a layout using flexbox:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

header div has a fixed `height: 60px`, and main div takes the remaining height of screen:

```
html, body{
  100%;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;   
}
#header{
  height: 60px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
#main{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I got what I want:

[image: header and main div]

Then I want to display three boxes inside `#main` div: box_1, box_2 and box_3. 
box_1 and box_3 has the same height value, and box_2 *expand itself to take the remaining height of `#main`*:

[image: What I want:]

I add the following codes:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="box_1"></div>
      <div id="box_2"></div>
      <div id="box_3"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

#main{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#box_1, #box_3{
    height: 60px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
#box_2{
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The `#box_2` is invisible unless I set a height value to `#main` div. If height value is required, why should I still use flexbox...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you didn't specify `display: flex` on the `#main` container.

Therefore, the element is not a flex container, `flex-direction: column` is ignored, and the children are not flex items.

Keep in mind that [flex properties work only between parent and child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276). So your `display: flex` on the `body` element applies only to the children, but not other descendants.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 60px;               /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  background-color: lightgray;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;                 /* key addition */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box_1, #box_3 {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

#box_2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div id="box_1"></div>
  <div id="box_2"></div>
  <div id="box_3"></div>
</main>
```