# Is it bad practice to make a flex item a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a html layout like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    // content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 100vh applied to container div. And I need to vertically center content. I found I could vertically center everything inside content div if I apply the following CSS to both container and content, but I'm wondering if it's bad practice and if I should be doing something else instead?

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong or invalid with nesting flex containers. The [flexbox specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) neither prohibits nor even admonishes against the practice.

In fact, it's what you must do when you need to apply flex properties to the descendants of a top-level container, since flex layout works only between parent and child elements.

More details here: [Proper use of flex properties when nesting flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to achieve. Below a few results using different colors to make it more visible.

Using flexbox for both items.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 250px;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only using it for the container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 250px;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally only using it for the content

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 250px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to use it on your container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Fiddle example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/eq9y42nj/34/

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Inside the content div, I have two elements: an image and a text section. If I apply it only to the container, the text doesn't vertically center. I'm just wondering if it's bad practice/if it has any drawbacks if I apply it to both? Or if there's another solution that would center everything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eq9y42nj/36/ check this fiddle, I simulated an image with a red background container