# Flex divs with 50% parent width wrapping when not suppoused to

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I feel stupid for not being able to figure it out but for some reason I cannot make those divs to stay in one line. I expect them to be next to each other in one line since they both have half of parent divs `width` while keeping `flex wrap` in case if I added more divs.

Here is my code

```css
.aside__item {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
 }
.aside {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<aside class="aside"> 
            <div class="aside__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Aenean luctus pulvinar risus ut congue. Duis eu metus eros.
            </div>
            <div class="aside__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Aenean luctus pulvinar risus ut congue. Duis eu metus eros.</div>

        </aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some browser defaults causing the elements to have margins. Set the item's margin to be `0`

```
.aside__item {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyx9doba/

I recommend using something like normalize to reset all browser defaults to give you better control over your elements: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

**Update**: To retain the margin you need to reduce your width to be 50% minus the margin:

```
.aside__item {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y6jfadcw/

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem because I want the child divs to have `margins`

Comment: Not a problem, but this is the basis of the actual problem because your `aside_items` exceed 50% (width + margin). If you want to retain the margin you'll need your width to be less than 50%. I'll add the example above.

Comment: That seems to be right, also read your another comment I was convinced to this point that `margins` are also included in `box-sizing`, thanks. Also what confused me was that the calculated `widths` of the child `divs` were exactly `50%` of parent `div`

Comment: @aMJay yea I can see why - flex + width has some interesting behaviours so it's not always accurate.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by adding flex:1 to the child

```css
.aside__item {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    flex:1;
 }
.aside {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<aside class="aside"> 
            <div class="aside__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Aenean luctus pulvinar risus ut congue. Duis eu metus eros.
            </div>
            <div class="aside__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Aenean luctus pulvinar risus ut congue. Duis eu metus eros.</div>

        </aside>
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe got any idea why it doesn't work in my example?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you need to add `flex-direction` on the childs and remove `flex-flow`:

```
.aside__item {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    flex-direction: row; //need flex direction here
 }

.aside {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ao7hf6n9/

Comment: while this works I'm pretty sure `flex-direction` should be placed in the same class as the `display:flex`, any idea why that would make it work?

Comment: @aMJay Doesn't seem to matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/4194436 I always do it like this.

Comment: `flex-direction` applies only to flex containers. It does nothing when applied to the children.

Comment: Because you removed `flex-flow` from the container, which enabled `wrap`. The default is `nowrap`.

Answer (score 1):

The margin on the items causes your items to exceed 50%. If you reduce it to something like 40%, it will work fine. Alternatively, you can remove your margin.

```css
.aside__item {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">
  <div class="aside__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean luctus pulvinar risus ut congue. Duis eu metus eros.
  </div>
  <div class="aside__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean luctus pulvinar risus ut congue. Duis eu metus eros.</div>

</aside>
```

Comment: While this works, the width of the items including `margins` is exactly 50% of the parents and the `margins` don't make it exceed the `width` because of `box-siging:border-box` and this can be observed in computed styles of the elements, any idea why is it so?

Comment: @aMJay border-box only includes the padding and border-width in height/width calculations not the margin itself.